# How to set the limit for the dragging the div vise versa no more than minimum width which is 200

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I set minimum width for not allowing drag left to no width in the following sample?

```
const App = () => {
  
    const [initialPos,   setInitialPos] = React.useState(null);
    const [initialSize, setInitialSize] = React.useState(null);
  
    const initial = (e) => {
        
        let resizable = document.getElementById('Resizable');
        
        setInitialPos(e.clientX);
        setInitialSize(resizable.offsetWidth);
        
    }
    
    const resize = (e) => {
        
        let resizable = document.getElementById('Resizable');
      
        resizable.style.width = `${parseInt(initialSize) + parseInt(e.clientX - initialPos)}px`;
      
    }
    
    return(
        <div className = 'Block'>
            <div id = 'Resizable'/>
            <div id = 'Draggable'
                draggable   = 'true'
                onDragStart = {initial} 
                onDrag      = {resize}
            />
        </div>
    );
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

https://codepen.io/erikmartinjordan/pen/dyMEXJb?editors=0110

Comment: i believe we can find the difference between initial width before drag and the mouse cursor x position. then the difference will be the new width. if the new width is 200 we just need to stop the width state change happen again on that mouse position that resulting < 200 width.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your resize function to limit the width.

```js
const resize = (e) => {
    let resizable = document.getElementById('Resizable');
    let newWidth = parseInt(initialSize) + parseInt(e.clientX - initialPos);
    if (newWidth < 200) {
    newWidth = 200;
    }
    resizable.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
}
```

You can set 200 to be any maximum width. Just don't forget to change both 200 values, or even better make a variable for it!

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to move the end to either left or right with maximum of 200 pixels.

```
const initial = (e) => {
  let resizable = document.getElementById("Resizable");

  // lock the start position
  if (initialPos == null) {
    setInitialPos(e.clientX);
    setInitialSize(resizable.offsetWidth);
  }
};

const resize = (e) => {
  let resizable = document.getElementById("Resizable");
  // check for the absolute distance from the start point
  if (Math.abs(e.clientX - initialPos) < 200) {
    resizable.style.width = `${
      parseInt(initialSize) + parseInt(e.clientX - initialPos)
    }px`;
  }
};
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/amila15/pen/vYWgBGR)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think your answer does vise a versa. It should restrict from the left not from the right.